# Rails I18n locale returns different results throughout the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize2

I'm in the process of adding I18n to a legacy app running Rails 2.3.x but I have a very strange problem that I'm unable to solve. On a single page I18n.locale returns different results. In the sidebar I18n.locale returns 'en' (correct) but on the main content it returns 'de'. These are not even different partials, they are just in different divs.

I even tried deleting de.yml, but it still insists on showing certain areas of the page as belonging to the 'de' locale.

I'm at a loss here and really hoping someone have some insight.

EDIT: I've found that there is somehow a problem related to Globalize2.

Comment: it seems that the same field for the main page declares not the field

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit? I'm not sure what exactly you mean.

Comment: for example we have `locale.en.yaml`: consisting in `en: activerecord: title`, in the same german `locale.de.yaml`, there are no such record. So please show the both version here in the post.